# Qualcomm Gimbal Geofence Communication

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, ibeacon, gimbal

I created Geofences in Gimbal Manager, and was able to trigger place events also.
My problem is to communicate to iPhone device through Gimbal Manager.

Delegate methods are getting called
- (void)didGetContentDescriptors:(NSArray *)contentDescriptors

But contentDescriptors array is null. I was not able to figure why I was not able to get contents when Geofence communication is triggered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello bro I have the same issue...So have you find any solution for it.

Comment: Hi Sanny its working for me. Once confirmed the Geofence is enabled, am enabling the communication part.